# How to calculate Next Monday?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I am using SharePoint 2010 Workflow. I need to calculate Next Monday from today. I dont seem to see any ootb option that would let me determine the date for next Monday. Workflow takes .net Regex so I am not sure if this would be right method to determine next Monday. How would you determine next Monday?

Comment: I don't like Mondays.....

Comment: Cuz the silicon chip inside my head was switched to overload.

Comment: Also, more helpfully to the original asker, this might be a good question for the Sharepoint.se site: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If there a function to get DOTW from today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column and used following formula. Seemed to did the trick.

=[Today] + (6 - MOD(WEEKDAY([Today]),7)) + 7

However, follow the link below because [Today] in the formula gives error.
http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column